# How to use one big query instead of one by one queries in Yii2 Kartik GridView?

Tags: performance, gridview, yii2

I'd like to have a GridView to show data of multiple tables in Yii2. 
Just for an example, here is a simplified example of the database structure:

Table1: Entry

Table2: Name

Table3: NameOfSomething (name_id fk, entry_id fk)

Table4: Date (entry_id fk)

Table5: Place

Table6: PlaceOfSomething (place_id fk, entry_id fk)

Table7: PlaceOfSomethingElse (place_id fk, entry_id fk)

So lots of joins and also where clauses.

If I use ActiveRecord with Kartik GridView, it makes queries row by row to join other tables and put where clauses together. I need to show at least 500-1000 result rows without pagination. With this, even if one query takes milliseconds, it takes 10-100 seconds to retrieve all the data I need to show. 
I have an other solution with datatables.net, I have 1 big query and I give this to feed the table. It has 20-30 times better perfomance, which would be enough.
So the question, is there any way to feed the GridView in Yii2 with one big query instead of a lot of queries to improve performance - keeping the filter and the sorting features? If yes, how?

**!!UPDATE!!**

So the real problem is with the tables joined on the second level (like Place). It is still querying for each row. Here is my code as an example:

```
class Entry
...
public function getPlaceOfSomething() {
    return $this->hasOne(PlaceOfSomething::className(), ['id' => 'plcofsthg_id']);
}
public function getPlace() {
    return $this->hasOne(PlaceOfSomething::className(), ['id' => 'plcofsthg_id'])->joinWith('place');
}
public function getPlaceOfSomethingName() {
    return $this->Place->getPlaceName();
}

class PlaceOfSomething
...
public function getPlace() {
    return $this->hasOne(Place::className(), ['id' => 'place_id']);
}
public function getPlaceName() {
    return $this->getPlace()->one()['name'];
}

class Place is in the generated way, contains id and name
```

**From the log**

This gets everything in 1 query (still separated, but that's okay):

SELECT * FROM `place` WHERE `id` IN ('1', '2', '3', '29', '25', '85', '5', '27', '30', '168', '6', '14', '38', '45', '32', '133', '33', '10', '67', '1057', '69', '73', '74', '95', '46', '103', '107', '108', '101', '52', '42', '308')

And then all the queries again, one by one:

SELECT * FROM `place` WHERE `id`='33'

Comment: 1 query = eager loading, multiple queries = lazy loading, both completely possible with AR. to keep the sorting and filter features on related fields, you should read this wiki: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/#hh16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at eager loading vs lazy loading, like deacs told you. This is the official link: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#lazy-and-eager-loading

With datatables you will not solve the issue, you still have to load all the data and only eager loading will solve it. You should see a huge improvement in your view. Also use the debug toolbar to make sure you implement it properly and to watch the number of queries plummet.

Comment: There is an other problem. I have 3 level of joins: Entry -> NameOfSomething -> Name. Name is joined in the class of NameOfSomething. So if I do eager loading on Entry, the Name table still will be lazy loaded. Is there any way to fix this? (I have Name model in the Entry model as well already through NameOfSomething, and also I have all of the tables joined in the EntrySearch object)

Comment: Add that part to the query. You can always do a `$query = Delivery::find()->where('Delivery.status <> "deleted"')->joinWith('contact')->with('deliveryProducts.product');` as you can see I load contacts and I also load the products that are 2 tables away.

Comment: Yes, that was the last fix of this problem. Thank you!